# Функция пропускает другие условия

Tags: javascript, функции

Не могу понять почему функция пропускает все остальные условия и не уверен, что такие множественные ИЛИ можно использовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста)

```
   let currencySuffix;

   let suffixFinder = moneyOperation(currencySuffix);

   function moneyOperation(currencySuffix) {
   if (moneyInAmount % 10 === 2 || 3 || 4 ) {
       return 'рубля'
   } else if (moneyInAmount % 10 === 0 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 ) {
       return 'рублей'
   } else {
       return 'рубль'
   }
   }

   alert(`На ваш счёт поступило ${moneyInAmount} ${suffixFinder}`);
```

Comment: "не уверен, что такие множественные ИЛИ можно использовать" - подсказываю: использовать нельзя

Comment: ну так если не уверены, то откройте документацию да прочитайте.

Comment: условия, кстати, не полные все равно

Comment: понял спасибо. гуглить пытался, но видимо неправильно сформулировал свой запрос. сам недавно только начал учиться

Comment: @teran почему это неполные? `|| 3` будет же приведено к `true` и всё буде полным.

Comment: @nazarpunk неполные с точки зрения что выдаст "222 рубль"

Comment: @teran
222 при делении на 10 даст 2 в остатке и "рубля", но вот с х11-х14 будет засада

Comment: @Zombotron да, что-то не туда посмотрел. но все равно это не целиком правила.

Comment: @Zombotron если `moneyInAmount % 10 === 2` даст `false` то дальше последует `|| 3`, который вернёт `true` и посему всегда будет `return 'рубля'`.

Comment: @nazarpunk
да, условия там кривоватые, но я имел в виду,  что при прав. проверке на 2, 3, 4 склонение будет прав. и для 2, и для 222, но неправильным при 12 и х12

Comment: @Zombotron так то да, но не все могут нагуглить [функции](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html) склонения.

Comment: @nazarpunk, вообще,лучше так: (pseudocode) if ((num % 100 > 10 and num % 100 < 20) or (num % 10 > 4 and num % 10  < 10) or num % 10 == 0) return 'рублей'; elseif (num % 10 == 1) return 'рубль';else return  рубля';

Comment: @nazarpunk " так то да, но не все могут нагуглить функции склонения" - лично мне быстрее и проще велосипед наколхозить, чем в тоннах мусора искать. ))

Comment: @Zombotron, если проще, то почему бы и не да. Главное чтоб велосипед нормально работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше условие эквивалентно:

```
if (moneyInAmount % 10 === 2 || true || true) {
    return 'рубля'
} else if (moneyInAmount % 10 === 0 || true || true || true || true || true) {
    return 'рублей'
} else {
    return 'рубль'
}
```

А для склонения можете использовать эту [функцию](https://gist.github.com/znechai/1b25d0ee9a92e5b879175ab4f040dbbc):

```js
const pluralize = (count, words) => count + ' ' + words[(count % 100 > 4 && count % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][Math.min(count % 10, 5)]];


for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  //[`1 рубль`, `4 рубля`, `5 рублей`]
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div>Поступило ${pluralize(i, [`рубль`, `рубля`, `рублей`])}</div>`;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)